# Office Invalid XML error, file still opens in Office

Tags: excel, validation, schema, openxml

I have an .xlsx file that when run through the open Office SDK 2.5 generates an error that the document is invalid and contains multiple validation errors involving the slicerCache and invalid attribute values.

I can attach more information about the actual XML if needed from the xlsx file, however my question is actually this. Excel still opens the document without an error. Not even a request to "repair" the document.

I am curious why using the Microsoft open office XML SDK generates validation errors, yet office is still able to open these documents.

Does office make a best guess? Or is the SDK given by microsoft not entirely accurate??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatting issue as far as I can tell. When you save it in xlsx it saves it as a workbook, not a spreadsheet. I would save it in a different file format or see if there libraries that your sdk needs in order to process the xlsx. I've never worked with office sdk, but I get similar errors when I open xlsx in other programs. 99% of the time I can just change the format. (if you live dangerously you can just manual change the file extension in your folder to something itll read.)